# Does SharedPreferences use a certain character set?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have just noticed that SharedPreferences removes carriage return (\r) when storing a string.  Since it was quite costly for me to not know this, I would like to know if it removes any other characters.  In other words, does it use a certain character set.

```
SharedPreferences sp = activity.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.edit().putString("Foo", "\r\nfoo").commit();

//After restarting the app
SharedPreferences sp = activity.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String sFoo= sp.getString("Foo", ""); //returns "\nfoo", not "\r\nfoo"
```

Answer (score 2):

Good morning,

It is even worst: if you store the String "\r" into SharedPref, after killing and restarting application, the value from SharedPref will become "\n".

Another bug from our beloved Android platform, very annoying...

Cheers

Comment: By the way, I say "Good morning", because SO is filtering "hi" and "hello". That's weird!

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, does it use a certain character set.

[When you write your `SharedPreferences` to the disk](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#L598), it uses [`XmlUtils.writeMapXml`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/util/XmlUtils.java#L175), which outputs in `UTF-8`.

Comment: Thanks for the informaiton. Does UTF-8 exclude carriage return (\r or 0x0D)? Why isn't "\r" mapped to U+0013?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the UTF-8 (which supports all Unicode characters) and everything to do with the XML (which collapses whitespace characters).